# How do I send many variables to php in html form?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to write a web application in which students enter their timetable. For example: First period of Monday is math, second period of Monday is English,... first period of Tuesday is history, second period of Tuesday is biology,... etc.

So I write a form like this:

```
<form method="post" action="timetable_handling.php">
    <?php
        for ($period=1;$period<=9;$period++)
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            for ($day=1;$day<=7;$day++)
                {
                    echo "<td><input name="the_subject_of_the_nth_$period_on_$day" type="text"></td></tr>";
                     //the problem is here
                }
        } 
    ?>
</form>
```

So my question is, are there any ways to pass the many variables to another php file to handle without having to manually write its name explicitly?

Edit 1: I mean is there anyway to encode the period and day information in the name, so that when it sends to timetable_handling.php I can just loop through it to save it into sql database. Something like an array $subject[day][period].

I would be grateful if someone could help me.

Comment: What you do is just fine, except that you have a closer look at different ways to create that variable name. I suggest to look at `sprintf()`. Check the documentation. Oh, and you have to fix those quot chars. You cannot use the same to delimit the string and inside the string.

Comment: What do you mean by "many variables"? Can't you retrieve $_POST on the handler file?

Comment: @Bonatoc: It's hard to describe. The users enter 63 variables corresponding to the periods and days. I already wrote a loop, so I cant write the name of the input fields something like subject_of_third_period_monday. Are there any ways to make php regconize the $period and $day in the form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the following on your **timetable data entry** page:

```
<form method="post" action="timetable_handling.php">
    <table>
        <?php
            for ($period=1; $period<=9; $period++)
            {
                echo '<tr>';
                for ($day=1; $day<=7; $day++)
                    {
                        echo '<td><input name="subject_of_period_'.$period.'_on_day_'.$day.'" type="text"></td>';
                        //the problem is here
                    }
                echo '</tr>';
            } 
        ?>
    </table>

<input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
</form>
```

Then follow up with this script on your `timetable_handling.php`:

```
<?php

for ($day=1; $day<=7; $day++)
    {
        for ($period=1; $period<=9; $period++ )
            {
                ${'subject_of_period_'.$period.'_on_day_'.$day} = htmlspecialchars($_POST['subject_of_period_'.$period.'_on_day_'.$day],ENT_QUOTES);
                echo '<p>Subject of Period '.$period.' on Day '.$day.' is '.${'subject_of_period_'.$period.'_on_day_'.$day}.'</p>';
            }
    }

?>
```

It's secure and it works.

Comment: Thank you very, very much, it works indeed. I love Stack Overflow. If possible, can you elaborate on the syntax ${something} you used ? I don't know much about the manipulation of variable name. Is this something programmers usually do or do they use alternative methods ?

Comment: `${...}` is an unusual construct, not seen in many other scripting languages. It is called a `variable variable`. The syntax enables you to declare a variable name, which contains within it strings derived from the values of other variables. For more info,  see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: @Rounin - not so unusual, as it can be done in Javascript as well.

Comment: @Bonatoc - You might just have made my day. I'd always assumed that `variable variables` were not possible in `.js`. Do you have a link? Thanks.

Comment: Don't get too excited :-) Sorry, but only the classic methods : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript — I was reffering to angularJS, and also JQuery, where you can concatenate like ${"prefix_"+my_variable_variable}

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you format a variable name something like

```
        for ($day=1;$day<=7;$day++)
            { ?>
                <td><input name="subject['<?= $period ?>'][<?= $day ?>]" type="text"></td></tr>
                 //the problem is here
            <?php }
```

PHP will turn `$_POST['subject']` into a 2D array for you. (Note I make no promise this is free of syntax errors.)

Answer (score 0):

In the form handler you can loop through all the posted fields like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $field => $value)
{

}
```

Where $field would be the input-tag name and $value it's value.
If you have other form elements you can check which ones you need with some kind of prefix, like if the fieldname starts with 'the_subject', you know it's one of the fields that were dynamically added.

Answer (score 0):

sure, you already did part of the answer :)
first issue: you are not escaping your string properly:
Here is 1 another way

```
echo '<td><input name="'.$period.'_on_'.$day.'" type="text"></td></tr>';
```

As for handling the post here is what you can do. You might need to tweak it around to get the exact desired result. But you are talking about multidimentional array.

```
if (isset($_POST)){

    $something=array();
    foreach ($_POST as $single=>$value)
    {
        array_push($something, array('period_'.substr($single,0,1) => array('day_'.substr($single,-1)=>$value)));
    }
}

echo '<pre>'.print_r($something,true).'</pre>';
```

Good Luck.